# Refer SVG Definition From Another SVG

Tags: svg

I have a problem with SVG Use Element.Lets understand from example

**Svg1.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <polygon id="lens" points="65,50 185,50 185,75, 150,100 100,100 65,75"
       fill="none" stroke="purple" stroke-width="4"/>
       <radialGradient id="irisGradient">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="green" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="dodgerblue" />
       </radialGradient>
       <g id="eye">
         <ellipse cy="50" rx="50" ry="25" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
         <circle cy="50" r="25"/>
         <circle cy="50" r="10" fill="black"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

From the above svg I want to refer symbol in another SVG File

**SVG2.svg**

```
<svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g>
     <use xlink:href="Svg1.svg#eye" x="125" fill="url(Svg1.svg#irisGradient)"/>
     <use xlink:href="Svg1.svg#eye" x="250" fill="dodgerblue"/>
     <use xlink:href="Svg1.svg#lens"/>
     <use xlink:href="Svg1.svg#lens" x="125"/>
     <line x1="65" y1="50" x2="310" y2="50"
          stroke="plum" stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

SVG2.svg is working fine in Mozilla but in IE9 and Chrome it is not working. 
Do IE9 and Chrome support referencing symbols from another svg, or is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: A couple questions:  Are the files on a webserver or on a local file-system, and if a webserver are they on the same domain?  If they aren't both on the same domain webserver, file access restrictions could be a problem.  Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: Both the files are in Local file system.

Comment: Sounds like http://crbug.com/229081.

Comment: @ErikDahlström If it's the latest Chrome, the graphics should be used ok, it's only the style definitions that don't get properly copied over from the external file ([see test file](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20061213/htmlEmbedHarness/full-struct-use-05-b.html) -- I'm getting everything except the colour of the radial gradient correct on Chrome 34).  If the OP isn't seeing anything, my first guess is still local file access restrictions.  SubbuS: are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: No i didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

please remove [Svg1.svg] from links

```
<svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g>
        <use xlink:href="#eye" x="125" fill="url(#irisGradient)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#eye" x="250" fill="dodgerblue"/>
        <use xlink:href="#lens"/>
        <use xlink:href="#lens" x="125"/>
        <line x1="65" y1="50" x2="310" y2="50" stroke="plum" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```